# Is TimeStamp column unique?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, timestamp

Is `TimeStamp` unique in all rows?

Does it have a unique index on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

timestamp is a  data type that exposes automatically generated binary numbers, which are guaranteed to be unique within a database. timestamp is used typically as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes.

---

For more info, check [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) article.

Comment: how much is it's capacity? is it possible that we have `OverFlow` on `TimeStamp` Column?

Comment: @Kerezo The capacity will be at least 2^63 (if not 2^64). You'd need somewhere around 9.22×10^18 increments to overflow it.

Comment: @Kerezo Nowadays, it's near to impossible! You'll overflow timestamp if you insert something like 10000 per second during 122 years :P

Comment: @aF From my working those 10000 per second would take 58 million years to use up. (I only checked because the rate you mentioned would overflow facebook in about 4 months what with their 3.5m row updates a second - and that was just what they used in 2010)

Comment: This is not true in practice. Se my answer for explanation. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49918160/1444548

Answer (score 4):

From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), emphasis mine:

> Timestamp is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique
>   binary numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a
>   mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8
>   bytes. **The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does
>   not preserve a date or a time.** To record a date or time, use a
>   datetime data type.

It also provides this interesting note:

> Duplicate timestamp values can be generated by using the SELECT INTO
>   statement in which a timestamp column is in the SELECT list. We do not
>   recommend using timestamp in this manner.

In SQL server 2008 and later, the `timestamp` type has been renamed to `rowversion`, presumably to better reflect its purpose and value.

Answer (score 0):

The docs says

> unique binary numbers within a database

But in practice you can run into situations where this statement is not true. Since the value is generated from a `database global counter` you might run into problems when restoring databases and or using `timestamp` in tables in `tempdb`.

You can see the next value:

```
Select @@DBTS
```

Until SQL Server 2000 there was an undocumented command to change the value

```
DBCC CHECKDBTS (dbId, newTimestamp)
```

To change the timestamp in non ancient verswions of SQL server see this answer:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11088/149485