# unique timestamp generation in sql server

Tags: timestamp, unique, bulkinsert, sql-server-2016

I have a table in which the column which will accept only binary datatypes and is designed to accept time stamp as binary value. This particular column is primary key as well ,because of which when I am trying to insert  using the below function I couldn’t insert unique records .

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.unique_id_gen ()
RETURNS BINARY(13)
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @d DATETIME2(6) ,
                @ret_variable BINARY(13); 
                --select SYSDATETIME (); 
        SET @d = SYSDATETIME();
        SET @ret_variable = ( SELECT CONVERT(
                                         BINARY(13) ,
                                         '0x' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), @d, 112)
                                         + RIGHT(REPLACE(
                                                     REPLACE(
                                                         CONVERT(
                                                             CHAR(16), @d, 14) ,
                                                         ':' ,
                                                         '') ,
                                                     '.' ,
                                                     ''), 13),
                                         1));
        RETURN ( @ret_variable );
    END;
```

May be because sql server goes with set based approach for multiple inserts I am not getting multiple time stamp values even with 7 ms precision value. Could some one suggest a way we can generate a unique time stamp value for every insert operation if All insert I am doing as one batch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is TimeStamp column unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616502/is-timestamp-column-unique)

Comment: I cannot change datatype of existing tables @Tanner.I am even checking the possibil option of adding a sequence  after  3 precision milliseconds which would uniquely generate a number like this.I have tried with sequence number but couldn’t succeed since next values are not allowed inside functions. Is there any other better way to do this?
0x20180130150507252001000000
0x20180130150507252002000000
0x20180130150507252003000000
0x20180130150507253001000000
0x20180130150507253002000000
0x20180130150507253003000000
0x20180130150507253004000000